# How Creating and Parsing XML with JAXB?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have Three class In java(project,layer,image), I want parser all this file to XML but I have problem in parser this attribute to XML by JAXB class project have attribute from layer and layer have attribute from image.
 **What I need in the end :**

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
     <project  name="">
       <Layer id="1"> 
         <image id="1">
          </image>
         <image id="2">
          </image>
       </layer>
       <Layer id="2"> 
         <image id="1">
         </image>
         <image id="2">
         </image>
       </layer>
    <project>
```

**project class :**

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Project {
  private String name;
  private Layer[] layer;
 @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
  @XmlElement(name = "layer")
  public Layer[] getLayer() {
       return layer;
   }
}
```

**Layer class :**

```
public class Layer {
  private int id;
  private Image[] images;
  @XmlElementWrapper(name="Layer")
  @XmlAttribute(name="id")
    public int getId() {
    return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
    }
    @XmlElement(name="images")
    public Image[] getImages() {
    return images;
    }

    public void setImages(Image[] images) {
    this.images = images;
    }
}
```

**Image class:**

```
public class Image {
   private int id;
   @XmlElementWrapper(name="Image")
   @XmlAttribute(name="id")
     public int getId() {
    return id;
    }
     public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@XmlElementWrapper` is used to add a grouping element to collections.  It is not valid to use it on a non-collection property like you are doing.  If you remove it things should work.

If you are still unable to unmarshal:

1. Populate your model and see what XML looks like, see where it differs from your input XML and update your mappings accordingly.
2. Update your question to include any exceptions you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

XML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Project name="">
    <Layer id="1">
        <Image id="1"></Image>
        <Image id="2"></Image>
    </Layer>
    <Layer id="2">
        <Image id="1"></Image>
        <Image id="2"></Image>
    </Layer>
</Project>
```

Project class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="Project")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Project {

  private String name;
  private List<Layer> layers;

  @XmlAttribute(name ="name")
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }

  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }

  public List<Layer> getLayers() {
    return layers;
  }

  @XmlElement(name = "Layer")
  public void setLayers(List<Layer> layers) {
    this.layers = layers;
  }

}
```

Layer class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Layer {

  private int id;
  private List<Image> images;

  @XmlAttribute(name="id")
  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }

  @XmlElement(name="Image")
  public List<Image> getImages() {
    return images;
  }

  public void setImages(List<Image> images) {
    this.images = images;
  }
}
```

Image class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Image {

  private int id;

  @XmlAttribute(name="id")
  public int getId() {
    return id;
  }

  public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

And the test Class:

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    Project project = unmarshal();
    marshal(project);
  }

  public static void marshal(Project pr)
  {

    Project project;
    if(pr==null)
    {
      project = new Project();

      Image image1 = new Image();
      image1.setId(1);

      Image image2 = new Image();
      image2.setId(2);

      List<Image> images=new ArrayList<>();
      images.add(image1);
      images.add(image2);

      Layer layer1 = new Layer();
      layer1.setId(15);
      layer1.setImages(images);

      Layer layer2 = new Layer();
      layer2.setId(15);
      layer2.setImages(images);

      List<Layer> layers = new ArrayList<>();
      layers.add(layer1);
      layers.add(layer2);

      project.setName("peoject123");
      project.setLayers(layers);
    }
    else
    {
      project = pr;
    }

    try {

      File file = new File("src/project-out.xml");
      JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Project.class);
      Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

      // output pretty printed
      jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

      jaxbMarshaller.marshal(project, file);
      jaxbMarshaller.marshal(project, System.out);

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static Project unmarshal() {
    Project project=null;
    try {
      File file = new File("src/project.xml");
      JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Project.class);

      Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
      project = (Project) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(file);

    } catch (JAXBException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return project;
  }
}
```